# Creating an Apple ID without any connection to the Apple ecosystem?

Tags: apple-id

I don't have a Mac or an iOS device and I've *never* had either but…

I need an Apple ID to be able use a couple of dev tools for work.

I've tried using the [Create Your Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/account) web interface, but it *always* fails with "Your account cannot be created at this time."

[image: screenshot]

My guess is that my attempts are being rejected due to some anti-fraud measure, but I have absolutely no idea what it might not like about my submission.

I've tried with multiple phone numbers, personal and work email addresses, from my home IP address, from my workplace VPN, etc. All with the exact same result.

Is it actually possible to create an Apple ID using phone/email that have never been associated with an Apple device? Has anyone else succeeded at this?

Comment: There is Apple Support article [How to create a new Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/108647) which gives instructions for both Apple and non-Apple devices. Does any on them work for you?

Comment: I don't have a Mac or Windows PC (all Linux here!), but did eventually succeed in creating an Apple ID via the web interface. I'm pretty sure that Apple didn't like _something_ about the phone number(s) I was initially using to confirm my account… but not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this here in case there's anyone else out there who doesn't use Apple devices, but needs to create an Apple ID and access the Apple app store.

---

I eventually succeeded in *creating* an Apple ID via the [Create Your Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/account) web interface. (It seems Apple didn't like *something* about the phone number I was initially using to confirm my account… but not sure what.)

After that, however, I faced a *new problem*.

I want to use [ipatool](https://github.com/majd/ipatool) to extract iOS software package distributions from the Apple app store, but after authenticating, `ipatool` was giving me errors like the following…

```sh
$ ipatool search "keywords on app store"
ERR error="you have not used this Apple ID on the app store before"
```

It seems Apple really wants to prevent me from accessing the app store until it thinks I have an actual Apple device linked to my account. (Eesh, what control-freakery ‍♂️.)

So then I tried [logging in to my new Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/sign-in) on the web, and browsing the web interface for iOS apps on https://apps.apple.com … but this *still didn't enable `ipatool` to work*.

However, I eventually discovered a solution.

I visited https://music.apple.com, and used my new Apple ID to sign in, and… **then `ipatool` started working** with my Apple ID.

Happy hacking.